# How to get a random selection of papers based on certain criteria?

Tags: publications, data, bibliometrics, databases, doi

What would be a good (easy, quick, replicable) way to get a random selection of, say, 1000 papers (DOIs) based on specific criteria, such as that they ought to have been:

- published in journals of a specific discipline (e.g., Political Science)
- published in a specific year (e.g., 2015)

I am agnostic about the data source. However, openly licensed sources are preferred over other ones. For instance, *CrossRef* or *OpenAlex* would be preferred over *Scopus* or *Web of Science*.

Comment: Sadly, you can probably only get a "random selection" over those you are able to find and list, not the entire universe. Don't forget to consider sample bias in whatever you do. But if you can get such a list, just index them and use a random number generator.

Comment: Many (most?) journals have a consistent format for their DOIs, you could try this: https://www.crossref.org/documentation/retrieve-metadata/xml-api/doi-to-metadata-query/ but you'd have to identify the journals and their formats by hand, AFAIK

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I have read an answer on this site that DOI formats are not necessarily consistent over time for a given journal, I cannot find it at the moment, though.